# Removing dotted outline around header on active tab in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When I select a tab from my `TabControl` in `WPF` I get a dotted outline or border or w/e you wanna call it around the header:
[image]

My question is: is there an option for this to **not** show, because it's kind of annoying. When the whole window isn't active this outline doesn't show, and still I would like to have it removed when the window's active.

And I'm sorry for the stupid question but I just couldn't think of what exactly to search in `Google`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FocusVisualStyle` is what you looking for, set this property to null for `TabItems` in common style-

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Page1"/>
        <TabItem Header="Page2"/>
        <TabItem Header="Page3"/>
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and the support!